# Get the Linux Kernel make process to rebuild modified files

Tags: build-process, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm [building a custom Ubuntu kernel](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2008/10/28/how-to-compile-a-custom-kernel-for-ubuntu-intrepid/) and have modified one of the source files.  When I issue the build command:

```
NOEXTRAS=1 skipabi=true skipmodule=true fakeroot debian/rules binary-insp8600
```

it rebuilds the debs, but none of the modified source files are rebuilt.

What's up?  Do I have to do a completely clean rebuild every time I modify a source file?

That doesn't make any sense.

The file modified was `./init/main.c`.

As a note binary-insp8600 is a custom flavor I created for my Inspiron 8600 laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debian/rules` is not the kernel Makefile. It has no way of knowing the file you edited is a dependency of the final kernel, since these dependencies are in the real Makefile.

In fact, I would expect the `debian/rules` `build` target (the one which actually does the compilation) to depend only on a "flag" file it creates after finishing the build. If that is the case, a simple workaround would be to remove that "flag" file; it would then compile everything again (by calling the kernel's `Makefile`, which would know how to do a partial rebuild. Of course, that's assuming the `build` target does not try to be tidy and do a `make clean` or equivalent...)

(I did not look at the `debian/rules` for the package you are using, so I might be wrong, but at least it is a start.)

Comment: Good guess.  There is a directory debian/stamps which contains build stamps.  Delete those and it will re-run make.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do a clean build if the dependancies in the Makefile are correct.

Is the file you changed a header file? If it is then run makedepend to add the header file dependencies automatically :)

If it isn't a header file then their really should be a dependency in the Makefile if it is part of the compilation, have a search and make sure the target you are using depends on the module you want to compile

Comment: Did you search for main in your Makefile (not main.c)? Is it there? It must be if it is ever to be compiled.

Comment: Of course it's in the make file, as you say - how would it get compiled in the first place otherwise?